# Export include directories of custom target to consumer

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a standalone library at `my-library/` with a custom target that generates some headers via an external command. In order to export the directory containing these headers as consumable from a parent directory, I'd like to do the following:

```
add_custom_target(my-target ALL
    COMMAND ...
)
target_include_directories(my-target
    INTERFACE my_include_directory/
)
```

and consume it from the parent project:

```
add_subdirectory(my-library)
add_executable(consumer ...)
add_dependencies(consumer my-target)
```

which semantically feels normal to me and `my_include_directory/` would be visible to `consumer`. However this results in:

```
target_include_directories called with non-compliant target type
```

Best solution I could come up with is to export the include directories from my library as a variable:

```
add_custom_target(my-target ALL
    COMMAND ...
)
set(MY_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS my_include_directory/ PARENT_SCOPE)
```

and consume the include directories via this variable:

```
add_subdirectory(my-library)
add_executable(consumer ...)
add_dependencies(consumer my-target)
target_include_directories(consumer PRIVATE ${MY_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

which is not ideal. Is there a better solution or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Just create **IMPORTED library target** (say `my_lib`) which incapsulates all information about your library, needed for compilation and linking: library file, include directories and so on. So you could use `add_executable(consumer my_lib)` for link with your library and consume all its properties. It is possible to specify dependencies between IMPORTED library target and the custom target which creates the library file and the headers: `add_dependencies(my_lib my-target)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build the library with the main project then you probably want to expose the generated headers as an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries).  This way the consuming target doesn't care or know the headers are generated and just uses [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) like normal.
You also probably don't want to use a [add_custom_target()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) for generating the headers.  Per the documentation:

> The target has no output file and is always considered out of date

This means that the headers will always be generated when the building.  Instead of only building when the input has changed.

Below is an example of using a [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#command:add_custom_command) to generate a header and hooking up via [add_custom_target()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) to an [interface library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries).

`my_library/CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(INPUT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/header.in")
set(GENERATED_HEADER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some_header.h")

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GENERATED_HEADER}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${INPUT_FILE} ${GENERATED_HEADER}
    DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILE}
    )

# Per the docs for add_custom_command, we use a custom target depending
# on the generated header to ensure it is only generated at most once per
# build
add_custom_target(local_target DEPENDS ${GENERATED_HEADER})

add_library(my_library INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(my_library INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# Per docs for add_dependencies
#
#   Dependencies added to an imported target or an interface library are
#   followed transitively
# 
# This ensures that the `local_target` will be built prior to anything that may end
# up using `my_library`.
add_dependencies(my_library local_target)
```

`my_library/header.in`

```
#define SOME_DEFINE 4
```

`./CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(example)

add_subdirectory(my_library)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE my_library)
```

`./main.cpp`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "some_header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("The value is %d.\n", SOME_DEFINE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you distribute binaries, just add a `install` instruction for the directory and make sure to list the directory you install headers to via `INCLUDES DESTINATION` of `install(TARGETS)`:

```
add_library(my-library ...)

add_custom_target(my-target ALL
    COMMAND ...
)

set(_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR my-library/includes)

add_dependencies(my-library my-target)
install(DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated-includes/" DESTINATION ${_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR})
install(TARGETS my-library EXPORT my-library
    LIBRARY DESTINATION my-library/lib
    INCLUDES DESTINATION ${_INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR})

install(EXPORT my-library DESTINATION my-library/lib/cmake FILE my-library-config.cmake)
```

This way you should get a config script to deploy alongside the lib which can be used with `find_package` to get a imported target `my-library` (assuming the `my-library` installed dir or its parent is in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`).

```
find_package(my-library REQUIRED)

add_executable(consumer ...)
target_link_libraries(consumer PRIVATE my-library)
```